# How to change bash to default ( -bash-4.1$ to bhargavd@ip-10-0-0-1 ~ )

Tags: linux, bash

/etc/passwd

```
bhargavd:x:501:501::/home/bhargavd:/bin/bash
```

$echo 0

```
-bash
```

echo $SHELL

```
/bin/bash
```

[image]

I want like `bhargavd@ip-10-0-0-1`

Comment: If this is about changing the prompt in the shell, then you should ask over on [unix/linux exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). There's already a [question on it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35777/how-to-change-the-prompt-in-linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://bashrcgenerator.com/ to generate your own prompt.

In your case you can add the following to your bashrc and reload it to achieve the prompt you want.

```
export PS1="\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```